# Why does these two sqls give different result?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I execute these sqls in PL/SQL.

The original sql is:

```
select  * from (
  select RecID,TaskNum from umstat.tostatinfo
  where RecID in (select recid from umstat.tostatinfo where StreetID = 101 and checkNum > 0)
  order by recID desc  
) where rownum >= 1 and rownum <= 50
```

`RecID` is the primary key of umstat.tostatinfo. This sql will empty the column `TaskNum` and give the result below:

[image]

The weird thing is that If I delete the fourth line(`order by recID desc`) or remove the outermost restriction imposed by where(`where rownum >= 1 and rownum <= 50`) then the column `TaskNum` will come alive:

[image]

In order to use the function provided by `order by` and `rownum` I simplify original sql to a more concise one:

```
select  * from (
  select RecID,TaskNum from umstat.tostatinfo
  where StreetID = 101 and checkNum > 0
  order by recID desc 
) where rownum >= 1 and rownum <= 50
```

Result of this sql looks normal:

[image]

**More tests:**

Replace subquery to plain ids `(447914,447912,447905)`:

```
select * from (
  select RecID,TaskNum from umstat.tostatinfo
  where RecID in (447914,447912,447905)
  order by recID desc  
) where rownum >= 1 and rownum <= 50
```

Result is:

[image]

Change `recid` to `TaskNum` in subquery:

```
select  * from (
  select RecID,TaskNum from umstat.tostatinfo
  where TaskNum in (select TaskNum from umstat.tostatinfo where StreetID = 101 and checkNum > 0)
  order by recID desc  
) where rownum >= 1 and rownum <= 50
```

Result is:

[image]

I want to know what makes all these happen underground, thanks for your time.

---

Comment: Strange. If `recid` indeed has a unique constraint as you say, I can't see any reason why your first query would return `null` for `tasknum` and non-null values for the 2nd query. I'm also surprised that the results of your last query appear to be in ascending order of `recid` - perhaps your SQL Dev sql window has a sort order preference on that column that is undoing the native sort order from the query. p.s. `rownum` always starts from 1 so there's no need for `rownum >= 1`.

Comment: *what is the result of* `select RecID,TaskNum from umstat.tostatinfo where RecID IN (447914,447912,447905)`

Comment: @Used_By_Already `TaskNum` is not null, result is normal.

Comment: You say this is in PL/SQL - can you run this query instead using aliases: `select x.RecID,x.TaskNum from umstat.tostatinfo x where x.RecID in (select y.recid from umstat.tostatinfo y where y.StreetID = 101 and y.checkNum > 0) order by x.recID desc`

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Yes, the result is normal, but TaskNum will still be null if I wrap your sql in  `select  * from (your_sql) where rownum >= 1 and rownum <= 50`

Comment: Post the entire result set.